# Launch Windows Store Application in C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-store

I'm looking to launch the Windows Store from my application.

Short version of the story: I need to strongly encourage users to go into the Windows store and download the Windows 8.1 update. I will be creating a one-time dialog to inform users that they should update and then have a button that will bring them as close to downloading said update as I can possibly get them.

Why do I need to do this? Decree from on high. It's my job so please no "you shouldn't do this because...".

Back to the question at hand: Given that program files and, indeed, windows itself can theoretically be installed to a random folder or drive. How can I reliably launch the Windows store, preferably with some wacky Windows store URL that gets the user as close to the aforementioned update as possible.

Answer (score 3):

ms-windows-store:WindowsUpgrade

Comment: Mind if I ask, where/how did you find the "WindowsUpgrade" bit?

Comment: ~2 hrs of digging through various disorganized MS errata

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ms-windows-store` protocol to create a URI to launch the Windows Store (and land on your app's page)

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974767.aspx

I assume you can then use WinRT's [`LaunchUriAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) to launch the URI from within a WinRT application.

If you want to include this URI in a webpage, beware that only FireFox and IE support this protocol (as far as I know).

Comment: This seems to be good for getting links to MY OWN apps but is there any way I can get the link for the Windows 8.1 updater?

Comment: @JoshuaPech I'm not sure how the updates work, but isn't a Windows 8.1 update the same as a Windows 8.1 App?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. My orders are to get people as close as possible to the Win8 -> Win8.1 official update.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Why would people search for "My App for Windows 8.1"? I don't want to link them to the Windows 8.1 version of my app. I want to link them to WINDOWS 8.1 ITSELF.

Comment: @JoshuaPech Nevermind, I'll retract my comments. I thought you meant you wanted your users to update your app to a version compatible with 8.1. Now I realize you want your users to update their **OS** to 8.1... My bad

Comment: I tried this on WIndows Phone 8.1 and it launched the Xbox Music app, not the Windows Store :-\